# Transparent window containing opaque text and buttons

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi+, gdi

I'm creating a non-intrusive popup window to notify the user when processing a time-consuming operation.  At the moment I'm setting its transparency by calling `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` which gives me a reasonable result:

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3144/transparentn.jpg](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3144/transparentn.jpg)

However **I'd like the text and close button to appear opaque** (it doesn't quite look right with white text) while keeping the background transparent - is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry there is no PM functionality on stackoverflow - hence i have to make a comment here - would you share the code for the final solution - similar to what Koro pointed out? thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to do "proper" alpha in a layered window you need to supply the window manager with a PARGB bitmap by a call to `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

The cleanest way to achieve this that I know of is the following:

1. Create a GDI+ `Bitmap` object with the `PixelFormat32bppPARGB` pixel format.
2. Create a `Graphics` object to draw in this `Bitmap` object.
3. Do all your drawing into this object using GDI+.
4. Destroy the `Graphics` object created in step 2.
5. Call the `GetHBITMAP` method on the `Bitmap` object to get a Windows `HBITMAP`.
6. Destroy the `Bitmap` object.
7. Create a memory DC using `CreateCompatibleDC` and select the `HBITMAP` from step 5 into it.
8. Call UpdateLayeredWindow using the memory DC as a source.
9. Select previous bitmap and delete  the memory DC.
10. Destroy the `HBITMAP` created in step 5.

This method should allow you to control the alpha channel of everything that is drawn: transparent for the background, opaque for the text and button.

Also, since you are going to be outputting text, I recommend that you call `SystemParametersInfo` to get the default antialiasing setting (`SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING`), and then the `SetTextRenderingHint` on the Graphics object to set the antialiasing type to the same type that is configured by the user, for a nicer look.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll need two top level windows rather than one - one that has the alpha blend and a second that is display above the first with the opaque text and button but with a transparent background.  To accomplish this with a single window you'll need to use the [UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633556%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call, but using this will cause your buttons to not redraw when they are interacted with (hover highlights, focus etc.)

It is possible that if this application is for Vista only there is a new API call that you can use, but I do not believe it is available in XP or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, you'll need to try it, but since everything is a window, you could try setting the layered attributes for your button to make it opaque.

As for the text, you may be able to put that in its own frame with a set background and foreground color, and modify its layered attributes to make the background color transparent...

But since these are child windows and not the top-level window, I really don't know that it'll work.