# C++: How do I use SetLayeredWindowAttributes() only on a parent window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transparent window containing opaque text and buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294805/transparent-window-containing-opaque-text-and-buttons)

I'm trying to manipulate an existing window with **C++**.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is set the parent window transparent via first setting its window style to `WS_EX_LAYERED` and then using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` with the right values.

The problem is that that will set the child windows to transparent also, which will make the whole program transparent (obviously a problem).

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Image demonstrating the problem: [image]

As you might see, I set the taskbars window style to `WS_EX_LAYERED`, but for example the window `MSTaskSwWClass` (the window that has the running application icons) is also affected.

**EDIT2** Tried `UpdateLayeredWindow()` with the exact same outcome.

Comment: Even if the problem is pretty similar, I don't think the answers will be the same. First of all, I'm not creating the window myself, second I'm not using any bitmaps nor GDI(+). Also, I tried dicking around with UpdateLayeredWindow(), but it didn't change anything (might be because I don't understand how to use it..)

Comment: The opacity and transparency effects you ask for will always be applied to any child windows as well.  The only way to avoid this is to put a top-level window on top of that parent window.

Comment: ...How would I do that in this case..?

Answer (score 0):

As of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Windows 8:**  The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows.
 Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED **only for top-level** windows.

So it will not set layered attribute to 'child' windows.

Show us screenshot and/or code.