# Common Controls on a Transparent Window?

Tags: winapi, transparency, common-controls

While there are lots of variations of the question, there doesn't seem to be a specific answer to a simple case of wanting to use built-in common controls on a transparent window using Win32.    I don't want the controls to be transparent, I just want the border around it to be transparent.  I can't believe MS didn't update the .dll's to handle transparency when they added it, but I guess they forgot?  Is there a specific method that works.  A button can get close with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, but flaky where it works most of the time but at times part of the border shows up. Edit controls, change depending on when get focus or not.

So the question is simply:

Is there a way to make common controls on transparent window so there is no white border around them?

If not, is there a good replacement library that does it via owner draw?

If some, which ones and what is the method?

Seems silly to reinvent the wheel just because of the area around the control.

TIA!!

Comment: Basically the controls aren't designed for this, the border is designed to blend into the background and with a transparent background you'll see it.

Comment: Hi, user3161924   Can you provide an example about the issue,such as code and screenshot.

Comment: And what version of your windows?

Comment: Vista or later only needs to be supported.  Think for example adding to the MS Win7 SDK Sample for a DeskBand.

Comment: @user3161924 hi, I want to say that WS_EX_TRANSPARENT does not make a window transparent.  It tells Windows that if a Windows is below another Window, it doesn’t need to paint its background since it is covered. The translucent window can be done by layering Windows and setting the opacity.As I pointed out in the answer

Comment: ok, but the method requires owner draw.  I don't need the button itself to have any transparency, just that it sitting on a transparent window works (without the white border it creates).   I guess I'll need to do owner-draw, so I'll probably just create a graphic icon and just draw it.  Presume the transparency in the icon will work for rounded corners.

Comment: Yes, according to your idea, you need transparent windows and opaque buttons, including icon on the button, which all require owner draw.All need to be done by controlling alpha color channels.Because the control button is created based on the parent window handle, it inherits the transparency of the parent window.

Comment: ok, i don't need my icon to be transparent, i may just draw `RoundRect` and then `DrawState` the icon on it?   Is there a code sample available of your method rather than pseudocode?

Comment: I've seen your latest post, and I see what you mean. Repainting the background of the button control removes what you call the white border.

Comment: okay, how do I force a repaint of only the background so the control doesn't repaint over it again?

Comment: This is another question, I suggest you create a new post to ask.

Comment: Okay, new question created [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694648/how-do-i-force-a-repaint-of-only-the-background-so-a-control-doesnt-repaint-ove)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can take the following steps to achieve this effect.

1.Create a `GDI+` Bitmap object with the `PixelFormat32bppPARGB` pixel format.

2.Create a `Graphics` object to draw in this `Bitmap` object.

3.Do all your drawing into this object using `GDI+`.

4.Destroy the `Graphics` object created in step 2.

5.Call the `GetHBITMAP` method on the Bitmap object to get a Windows `HBITMAP`.

6.Destroy the `Bitmap` object.

7.Create a memory DC using `CreateCompatibleDC` and select the `HBITMAP` from step 5 into it.

8.Call `UpdateLayeredWindow` using the memory DC as a source.

9.Select previous bitmap and delete the memory DC.

10.Destroy the `HBITMAP` created in step 5.

This method should allow you to control the alpha channel of everything that is drawn: transparent for the background, opaque for the button.

A similar discussion: [Transparent window containing opaque text and buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294805/transparent-window-containing-opaque-text-and-buttons)